# Oauth 2.0 restrict users within organization

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I had the issue to restrict users within the organization using Oauth 2.0 API.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved it by selecting application type to `internal`.

Now, if the users will try to authenticate the user from the email other than organization email. He will get an error message: `This client is restricted to users within organization`

**Notes:** The Google developer account should be of the same organization, to which you want to restrict the user oauth

For detail steps you can see the following attached screenshot.

`Adding Intenal domain setting screenshot`

[image]

`Google message will be shown to other users screenshot`

[image]

Comment: This is good, but I'd also like to select what users in the organization are allowed to use the application. Any idea if this is possible?